# Why can't LaTeX find my figures: subfigure package

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a LaTeX main document that receives input from several sub-documents. The main document contains `usepackage{subfigure}`. In one of those sub-documents I have the following:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{./path/to/fig1.pdf}}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat{{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{./path/to/fig2.pdf}}}
    \caption{On the left, a figure. On the right, another figure.}
    \label{TwoFigures}
\end{figure}
```

Figures that are not contained in `subfloat` appear without any problems. Why can't LaTeX find these two figures?

Comment: (i) please extend your code fragment to complete small document which should has loaded only packages relevant to your problem; (ii) `subfigure` (which doesn't support `\subfloat` environment) is obsolete package replaced with `subfig` (which support `float`) or instead ot you can use `subcaption`; (iii) why you use double pairs of curly braces in `\subfloat`? It is sufficient to use only one pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to an answer:

- package `subfigure` is obsolete package, which not define environment `float`, consequently it generate at use of `subfloat` error message `environment unknown` or similar
- instead of it you should use the package `subfig`, which is replacement for `subfigure` and define `subfloat` environment
- instead scaling of image with `scale` I suggest to define appropriate image width

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document delete option "demo"
\usepackage{subfig}         % <---


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{./path/to/fig1.pdf}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{./path/to/fig2.pdf}}
\caption{On the left, a figure. On the right, another figure.}
    \label{TwoFigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but I get a new error: captionwidth already defined. Any idea what that's about? Do I have to call usepackage{subfig} before or after other packages to avoid it?

Comment: @StatsSorceress, without seeing preamble of your document, I cant say anything. My MWE doesn't gives any error or warnings or generate bad boxes.

Comment: I just got it working, thank you. In the preamble, I had imported ccaption and set the caption width to be different, and for some reason that disagreed with subfig. Many thanks.

Comment: @StatsSorceress, instead of the `ccaption` I would rather use `caption` package.